# Using if directive in for directive at angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular. I'm creating a table dynamically. So I'm creating with ngFor directive. But, type of some columns are Date. So, I want casting that. So, I want to use if case. I wrote below like c# razor syntax. But, how can I do in angular?

```
<tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
  <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
    if(col.type == "Date")  ???????????
       {{rowData[col.field] | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
    else   ???????????????
        {{rowData[col.field] }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: just use *ngIf = "rowData[col.type] == "'Date'"

Comment: Date should be in single quotes 'Date'

Comment: But how I cast rowData[col.field]? Where am i write date pipe @Asanka

Comment: that below answer is the solution :P

Comment: I think, you misunderstand me. I want  like SureshKumarAriya' s answer. But without ng-container

Comment: if you don't want ng-template use *ngIf = "rowData[col.type] != "'Date' same as above

Comment: I think you're not right @Asanka. Where will yo write {{rowData[col.field] | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} in your solution (Pay attention to date pipe)?

Comment: No i suggest a way it should inside a div.

Comment: If you want i can add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by @NIVINCEN's answer help. The solution is **ternary if**. By using ternary if, you can do with only one row code and without using any span, div or ng-template.

```
<tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
  <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
    {{ col.type =='Date' ? (rowData[col.field] | date:'dd/MM/yyyy') : rowData[col.field]}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
  <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
    <ng-container *ngIf="(rowData[col.type] == 'Date'); else defaultTemplate;">
       <span>{{rowData[col.field] | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #defaultTemplate>
        <span>{{rowData[col.field] }}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to solve with not using any tag like ng-container @SureshKumarAriya

Comment: ng-container won't add any extra HTML element in the DOM. It's like virtual HTML Element.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I thinkk that is extra html element. This is what I'm looking for. Thanks. @SureshKumarAriya

Comment: I added my solution to answer. "Ternary if" is what i was looking for. That is solution without adding any div, span or ng-container @SureshKumarAriya. Thanks for your reply again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this?

```
 <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
        <div  *ngIf = "rowData[col.type] == "'Date'" >
           {{rowData[col.field] | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
        </div>
        <div  *ngIf = "rowData[col.type] != "'Date'" >
            {{rowData[col.field] }}
      </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I added my solution to answer. "Ternary if" is what i was looking for. That is solution without adding any div, span or ng-container. @Asanka

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```js
data = [
    {"name":"row1", "type": "date", "value": "Wed Oct 10 2018"},
    {"name":"row2", "type": "email", "value": "test@test.com"},
    {"name":"row3", "type": "date", "value": "Wed Oct 10 2018"},
    {"name":"row4", "type": "phone", "value": "+919876543210"}
  ];
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let row of data">
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
      <td>{{row.type}}</td>
      <td>{{row.type=='date' ? (row.value | date:'dd/MM/yyy') : (row.value)}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @NIVNCEN. "Ternary if" is what i was looking for. I added answer (convert to original code) by your help.